# Are some glitches corrected on the virtual console version of old games like Pokemon red/blue/yellow

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, virtual-console, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

Based on the previous games realesed on the virtual console from old Nintendo  platforms like Game Boy. Does anyone know if a known glitch or exploit on the original game were fixed on the new VirtualConsole version?

Being more specific, what actually worries me is if we are going to be able to capture Mew in the VC version of Pokémon Red/Blue/Yellow using the [known glitch](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mew_glitch) of the original version or if it will be fixed.

Comment: I have bought only a view VC games for the Wii and WiiU and to me and the glitches I know they were still their. Super Mario World and Super Metroid. Only thing I can say it get it and try it, they aren't that expensive and everyone loves Pokémon

Comment: If you're OCD and wants Mew for that, then I guess it might be an issue, but seriously, in the original Red/Blue/Yellow a team of 6 Alakazam is more than enough to WTFPWN everything you fight.

Comment: @Nelson That's irrelevant and has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Hence a comment and not an answer.  I'm just answering the question indirectly with regards to the reason for getting Mew, as opposed to answering the direct question about glitches (to obtain Mew).

Comment: @Nelson you imply you know the reason for getting Mew, to battle with it. Personally I would just get it to complete the pokedex "to catch 'em all".

Comment: @Nelson No one is asking about the reason for getting Mew. Nor to WTFPWN everything you fight. In addition, a comment can be as much irrelevant as an answer.

Comment: My guess is the glitch will still be around. There's no real reason they'd fix anything non-breaking. They *might* fix Missingno, as it can corrupt savegames (or maybe they'll decide that Missingno is too popular to remove). I don't know the Mew glitch, but it doesn't sound like anything dangerous. As long as the glitch isn't used to hack the 3DS and run homebrews on it, there's little reason to bother with it.

Comment: @Grirg Feel free to flag a comment as not constructive if you feel it is.

Comment: From what I understand, they're not even reprogramming the game to run on the 3DS. They wrote emulation software that acts like a gameboy/gameboy sp/etc. that runs on a 3DS, then run the original game binary on that. So, I agree with @Nolonar. Most bugs should be there.

Comment: However, it wouldn't be the first time a Virtual Console game got a first-party ROM hack -- the Mega Man Battle Network games, for instance, got significant changes on the Wii U VC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the games today, and can confirm that none of the glitches have been fixed.

The games really are true to the originals.

It is still unclear however whether you will be able to upload these glitched Pokemon into Pokemon Bank.

Comment: According to the nintendo direct the bank should be supported.

Comment: I know, I was talking about whether or not Nintendo would block you adding glitched Pokemon like Missingno. into the Bank like they have done with XY/ORAS. I'm betting that they will but it is still uncertain.

Comment: Got pokemon yellow VC on launch day and speedruned to test this but forgoted about this question

Answer (score 1):

The person who said that the experience overflow glitch was fixed is incorrect. On Pokemon Red, I was able to get a level 1 Nidoking and level him up to 100 without a problem.

The only "glitch", which isn't really much of a glitch at all, that I noticed didn't work anymore was the "nugget bridge trick." You beat all the trainers except for the last one, the one who gives you a gold nugget, lose against him, and go back only for him to give you another gold nugget and a rematch. Rinse, repeat. This was a good way to get a lot of money early in the game... But sadly, it didn't work and when I went back for another nugget and a rematch he acted as if I had won the battle against him.

Comment: The nugget bridge trick didn't work in Pokémon RBY, only in English versions of Pokémon Firered and Leafgreen.

Answer (score 0):

The only pokemon you cant really transfer into pokebank is mew. (Unless you want to do the 8F glitch which is REALLY long and hard to set up, plus 1 wrong move and say goodbye to your r/b/y save...... but anything else even with the expirience glitch will be allowed theprough poketransfer into pokebank

Answer (score 0):

Most of it is unfixed, if not, all; refer to all comments and research to find out what is still there. You can also visit this link to see what glitches remain:

https://glitchcity.info/wiki/Category:Generation_I_glitches

The only non glitched fix made to Virtual Console games that  I have noticed was after catching a Pokémon, if your box is full, that Pokémon is transferred to the next available box. As far as I know this is a Gen 1 fix made to Virtual console games.

Answer (score -1):

I've tested a few of the simpler glitches in the game. They left in the mew glitch and missingno., but the experience overflow glitch (the one that causes level 1 pokemon to jump to level 100) has been fixed.

Comment: Experience overflow glitch has not been fixed. Source: Just tested it.

Answer (score -3):

The jump from Level 1 to 100 is in The Blueversion of 2 DS Virtuel console fixed!
Tested it serveral times.

Comment: Hi Schmidt!  Are you saying that the Level 1-100 bug doesn't exist anymore (fixed) in Blue version?

Comment: Do you have a source, or anything new to add?