# Is it possible to transfer MissingNo. and other Gen 1 Glitch Pokémon to the PokéBank?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, pokemon-bank

As discussed in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246020/are-some-glitches-corrected-on-the-virtual-console-version-of-old-games-like-pok), Pokémon obtained through glitches such as Mew and Missingno are alive and well in the 3DS remakes of the first generation Pokémon games. One question remains, however: can these Pokémon be transferred to the Pokémon Bank?

Comment: BTW, the games in that question aren't 3DS remakes. They are on the virtual console; and emulate the original GB games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not true you can't transfer anything from first generation games to Pokémon Bank.

According to [Pokemon.com](http://www.pokemon.com/uk/pokemon-video-games/pokemon-bank/#pokemon-sun-pokemon-moon):

> Once Pokémon Bank has been updated, you'll be able to use it to transfer Pokémon you've caught in the Nintendo 3DS Virtual Console versions of Pokémon Red, Pokémon Blue, and Pokémon Yellow into your copy of Pokémon Sun or Pokémon Moon.

**EDIT:**

Regarding your question, Mew could only legally be obtained in Virtual Consoles through an event. All Mew received from such an event have an OT of "GF" and an OT ID of "22796". If a Mew does not have these values, it won't transfer.
See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309179/87579) for further info.

This is also true with MissingNo, it is actually a glitch and not a true Pokemon.
I remember when I tried to trade it from Blue to Gold, the game recognized it as a Slowpoke showing me a message like:

> Your Slowpoke has something wrong.

So I'm pretty sure you won't be able to trade MissingNo nor Mew (but only if its OT and ID differ from the event one).

Answer (score -1):

No, but they can be transferred to Gen 2, where they'll be valid Pokémon. They will, however, have the glitched moves, and may or may not be able to be transferred to Pokébank.