# How can I transfer the 'Mew Glitch' Mew to Pokebank?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, pokemon-bank

I recently got the glitched mew in Pokemon Yellow on the Virtual console but cannot transfer it.

I read that you need to make some changes to it using homebrew, but I have not used that before and saw as of the latest patch for the old 3ds (11.4.0-37u) homebrew is no longer working.

How else can I transfer it?

Comment: There is a very tedious and complex method; do you want to take that route?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue Are you referring to this: https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/5q8zlg/getting_gen_1_mew_in_yellow_guide_does_not_work/

Comment: Not necessairily, I was looking from: https://www.polygon.com/2017/1/26/14400184/pokemon-bank-mew-glitch

Comment: @Obinna Actually, the polygon article is linking to the Red/Blue version of the reddit guide, so yeah. Just so the disclaimer is here as well: This method involves a glitch belonging to the "ACE" group of glitches and any Pokemon modified in this way are considered hacked for purposes of online trading. Please disclose the use of this method if you decide to offer the Mew for trade in any online community.

Comment: I don't play Pokémon myself, so....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mew could only legally be obtained in Virtual Consoles through an event. All Mew received from such an event have an OT of "GF" and an OT ID of "22796". If a Mew does not have these values, it won't transfer.

Now if you want to obtain a Mew that passes the check, since the event is over, you will need to do either of these:

1. Name yourself GF at the start of the game, randomly get assigned the ID 22796. Restart until it works. Then just catch Mew through the Mew glitch.
2. Use homebrew or ingame glitches to change your ID (and OT if your didn't pick GF), then just catch Mew through a glitch.
3. Use ingame glitches to change your ID, then use ingame glitches to obtain a gift Mew. This method is easily repeatable once you managed to set everything up.

Note that any Mew obtained this way is considered hacked by virtually any community. While technically, there is no way to tell it's not legit, there's a moral component to it. If you intend to use any Mew obtained this way in trades, you should disclose your method.

Comment: I was able to generate and transfer mews via the poke bank using this glitch: [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/5q8zlg/getting_gen_1_mew_in_yellow_guide_does_not_work/)

Comment: @CSjunkie Yes, that would qualify as method #3. This glitch is an example of a group of glitches called "ACE" (short for arbitrary code execution), and a Mew transfered in this way is considered hacked in all communities where I've bothered to read the rules. That being said, if it's for your personal enjoyment only, there's nothing wrong with it and I have in fact successfully tested this method myself. Just please don't use it in trades without disclosing it was modified through an ACE glitch. ;)